Updating GRUB; ./configure doesn't make a makefile. Step 5 of INSTALL guide missing?
I am trying to update GRUB from 2.06 to 2.12, following the instructions in the INSTALL textfile included in the tarball (and at the bottom of the post). I am missing some dependencies, so I run:
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt install bison
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install automake #I'm not sure if this is required. I've tried the following commands both before and after installing automake. Same result.

#get the new version of grub
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/grub-2.12.tar.gz
tar -xf grub-2.12.tar.gz

#step 1 of the INSTALL textfile
cd grub-2.12

#skip step 2 and 3 and go to 4. my CLI has no scroll so I use tee to be able to view the full output
#even if I wanted to do step 3, I can't, ./bootstrap is not included in the tarball.
./configure |& tee ~/configoutput

#step 5 is missing, perhaps a typo, or perhaps the cause of my issue?
#step 6
make

#more steps after this but I haven't gotten to those yet...

All the commands complete successfully, except for make, which prints:
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
How do I get ./configure to create a makefile so I can use make? Thank you all!!
./configure seems to have no errors, as noted in ~/configoutput:
EDIT: after changing | to |&, ~/configoutput now includes an error! I am installing flex now and continuing the instructions, will report back soon.
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
checking whether the compiler is clang... no
checking for compiler option needed when checking for declarations... none
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for wchar.h... yes
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking for sys/types.h... (cached) yes
checking for features.h... yes
checking for linewrap.h... no
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for sys/socket.h... yes
checking for dirent.h... yes
checking for fnmatch.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... (cached) yes
checking for getopt.h... yes
checking for sys/cdefs.h... yes
checking for threads.h... yes
checking for limits.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking for langinfo.h... yes
checking for xlocale.h... no
checking for sys/mman.h... yes
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for strings.h... (cached) yes
checking for sysexits.h... yes
checking for crtdefs.h... no
checking for wctype.h... yes
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether _XOPEN_SOURCE should be defined... no
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for cmp... cmp
checking for bison... bison
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for gawk... (cached) gawk
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for bison... (cached) bison
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
configure: error: flex is not found

Relevant portion of `grub-2.12/INSTALL' from the tarball:
Building the GRUB
=================

The simplest way to compile this package is:

  1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code.

  2. Skip this and following step if you use release tarball and proceed to
     step 4. If you want translations type `./linguas.sh'.
  
  3. Type `./bootstrap'.

     The autogen.sh (called by bootstrap) uses python. By default autodetect
     it, but it can be overridden by setting the PYTHON variable.

  4. Type `./configure' to configure the package for your system.
     If you're using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might
     need to type `sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying
     to execute `configure' itself.

     Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
     messages telling which features it is checking for.

  6. Type `make' to compile the package.

  7. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
     the package. Note that many of the tests require root privileges in
     order to run.

  8. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
     documentation.

  9. Type `make html' or `make pdf' to generate the html or pdf
     documentation.  Note, these are not built by default.

 10. You can remove the program binaries and object files from the
     source code directory by typing `make clean'.  To also remove the
     files that `configure' created (so you can compile the package for
     a different kind of computer), type `make distclean'.  There is
     also a `make maintainer-clean' target, but that is intended mainly
     for the package's developers.  If you use it, you may have to get
     all sorts of other programs in order to regenerate files that came
     with the distribution.


Your configoutput doesn’t show stderr, so it won‘t show error messages written there. You need to use |& instead of | to capture everything.

@StephenKitt Brilliant! That reveals an interesting lead with the "flex not found" error message. If this ends up fixing it, I will reply again and ask you to submit that as an answer for me to accept!

The "Requirements" section in the GNU GRUB INSTALL file lists "*  Flex 2.5.35 or later". You need flex(1) (Fast LEXical analyzer generator) in addition to yacc(1) (Yet Another Compiler-Compiler). GNU's implementation of yacc is named bison.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential bison flex libgmp3-dev xorriso
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/grub-2.12.tar.gz
tar xzf grub-2.12.tar.gz
cd grub-2.12
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --disable-werror
#Create extra_deps.lst
echo "depends bli part_gpt" > grub-core/extra_deps.lst
make
sudo make install
grub-install --version

grub-install (GRUB) 2.12
refer my sample script.
https://github.com/PeterSuh-Q3/tinycore-redpill/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy.yml
